# Add custom cancel order status in bulk action in WooCommerce admin order list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to cancel all selected order on WooCommerce in the admin order list.

I have written the code but it's not working

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'my_register_bulk_action' ); // edit-shop_order is the screen ID of the orders page

function my_register_bulk_action( $bulk_actions ) {

$bulk_actions['mark_change_status_to_cancelled'] = 'Order Cancel'; // <option value="mark_awaiting_shipment">Order Cancel</option>
return $bulk_actions;


}



/*
 * Bulk action handler
 * Make sure that "action name" in the hook is the same like the option value from the above function
 */
add_action( 'admin_action_mark_change_status_to_cancelled', 'my_bulk_process_custom_status' ); // admin_action_{action name}

function my_bulk_process_custom_status() {


// if an array with order IDs is not presented, exit the function
if( !isset( $_REQUEST['post'] ) && !is_array( $_REQUEST['post'] ) )
    return;

foreach( $_REQUEST['post'] as $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $order_note = 'That\'s what happened by bulk edit:';
    $order->update_status( 'Cancelled', $order_note, true ); // "my-shipment" is the order status name 
}

// of course using add_query_arg() is not required, you can build your URL inline
$location = add_query_arg( array(
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'mark_change_status_to_cancelled' => 1, // mark_change_status_to_cancelled=1 is just the $_GET variable for notices
    'changed' => count( $_REQUEST['post'] ), // number of changed orders
    'ids' => join( $_REQUEST['post'], ',' ),
    'post_status' => 'all'
), 'edit.php' );

wp_redirect( admin_url( $location ) );
exit;


}

/*
 * Notices
 */
add_action('admin_notices', 'my_custom_order_status_notices');


function my_custom_order_status_notices() {

    global $pagenow, $typenow;


if( $typenow == 'shop_order' 
 && $pagenow == 'edit.php'
 && isset( $_REQUEST['mark_change_status_to_cancelled'] )
 && $_REQUEST['mark_change_status_to_cancelled'] == 1
 && isset( $_REQUEST['changed'] ) ) {

    $message = sprintf( _n( 'Order status changed.', '%s order statuses changed.', $_REQUEST['changed'] ), number_format_i18n( $_REQUEST['changed'] ) );
    echo "<div class=\"updated\"><p>{$message}</p></div>";

}


}
```

http://prntscr.com/oba9vg

Now it's showing Cancel Order under the bulk actions but unfortunately, function doesn't cancel the orders. what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this section:

```
foreach( $_REQUEST['post'] as $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $order_note = 'That\'s what happened by bulk edit:';
    $order->update_status( 'Cancelled', $order_note, true ); // "my-shipment" is the order status name 
}
```

Please use `"cancelled"` instead of `"Cancelled"`:

```
$order->update_status( 'cancelled', $order_note, true );
```

I think, then it'll work.

Comment: Works fine! Thanks!

Comment: I tested this on a pending payment status, It didn't cancel the order. Any possible ways to cancel and existing order with pending payment status